# How can i add item to cart by using event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am practicing html css and javascript . I want to know how can i add items to cart using an event listener. So far I have I tried using:

```
var addMouse = document.getElementById("addMouse");
addMouse.addEventListener("button", function() { addItemToCart(2); });
```

my function `addItemToCart()` validates the item and has one parameter which is the item number; in this case `2`. How can i go about solving this?

My html code for button is "button" and i dont want to use click:

```
 <button type="button" id="addMac" value="">Add</button>
```

Comment: I believe that it is `addMouse.addEventListener("click", yourFunction)`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener for more details.

Comment: Your question should **not** be "How to add item to cart" but rather **"How to register a click event"** which is covered on all over the internet and here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

if element addMouse is a button, you must define event click

```
addMouse.addEventListener("click", function() { addItemToCart(2); });
```

For call function addItemToCart how event handler

Comment: hi thanks for reply but i just want to use button event not click any help

Comment: public sample in codepen  to be able to help you, I do not understand what you're doing.